# Select group by values depending on conditions

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I want to create a query when the result pick the minimum value if its starting with 2 and if it starts with 4 and no value starting with 2 then max of 4

Input:

| value | fee |
| --- | --- |
| val_1 | 2001 |
| val_1 | 4003 |
| val_1 | 4002 |
| val_2 | 4512 |
| val_2 | 4186 |
| val_3 | 4125 |
| val_4 | 2058 |
| val_5 | 2296 |

```
SELECT
value, 
CASE 
    When CAST (fee as varchar) like '1%' THEN min(fee)
    ELSE max(fee)
END as fee_sorted
FROM table_1
GROUP BY 1
```

Output:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| val_1 | 2001 |
| val_2 | 4512 |
| val_3 | 4125 |
| val_4 | 2058 |
| val_5 | 2296 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find minimum from `2`s and maximum from `4`s and then use `coalesce`:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(value, fee) AS (
    values ('val_1', 2001),
        ('val_1', 4003),
        ('val_1', 4002),
        ('val_2', 4512),
        ('val_2', 4186),
        ('val_3', 4125),
        ('val_4', 2058),
        ('val_5', 229)
)

-- query
select value,
    coalesce(
            min(if(CAST(fee as varchar) like '2%', fee)),
            max(if(CAST(fee as varchar) like '4%', fee))
        ) as fee
from dataset
group by value
order by value;
```

Output:

| value | fee |
| --- | --- |
| val_1 | 2001 |
| val_2 | 4512 |
| val_3 | 4125 |
| val_4 | 2058 |
| val_5 | 229 |